# Extend global test object

Tags: jestjs

Is there any way to extend global jest `test` with some custom property? For example, I want implement some logic before test in this way:

```js
test.debug({ /* ... */ }, 'test', () => {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done either in [per-test setup file](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) or [custom environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string), in case a customization needs to interact with the environment on a deeper level:

```
it.whatever = (whateverArg, ...args) => {
    const cb = args[1];
    if (cb) {
         args[1] = cb.length ?
            (done) => { /* do whatever with whateverArg */ return cb(done); } :
            () => { /* do whatever with whateverArg */ return cb(); }
    }

    return it(...args);
};
```

All arguments need to be passed to `it` as is, test callback needs to be additionally taken care of because whether a test is considered asynchronous depends on callback function arity.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using ‘setupFilesAfterEnv’ works for me